# Value of type has no member

Tags: ios, swift

I have been following a swift course for a while and following along with the online tuts. Most of the issues I was able to find but I could use some help with this one.

In an app we are handling the errors that could happen for a user logging in through Firebase FIRAuth, my code looks like this:

```
class AuthService {

private static let _instance = AuthService()

static var instance: AuthService {
    return _instance
}

func login(email: String, password: String, onComplete: Completion?) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in

        if error != nil {

            if let errorCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!.code)  {
                if errorCode == .errorCodeUserNotFound {
                    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            self.handleFirebaseError(error: error!, onComplete: onComplete)
                        } else {
                            if user?.uid != nil {
                                //Sign in
                                FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error)
                                in
                                    if error != nil {
                                        self.handleFirebaseError(error: error!, onComplete: onComplete)
                                    } else {
                                        onComplete?(errMsg: nil, data: user)
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            } else {
                self.handleFirebaseError(error: error!, onComplete: onComplete)
            }
        } else {
            onComplete?(errMsg: nil, data: user)
        }

    })
}

func handleFirebaseError(error: NSError, onComplete: Completion?) {
    print(error.debugDescription)
    if let errorCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error.code) {

        switch(errorCode) {
        case .errorCodeInvalidEmail:
            onComplete?(errMsg: "Invalid email adress", data: nil)
            break
        case .errorCodeWrongPassword:
            onComplete?(errMsg: "Invalid password", data: nil)
            break
        case .errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse, .errorCodeAccountExistsWithDifferentCredential:
            onComplete?(errMsg: "Email already in use", data: nil)
            break

        default:
            onComplete?(errMsg: "There was a problem authenticating, try again", data: nil)
            break
        }

}
```

On compiling I get an error in the first func at:

```
if let errorCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!.code)
```

saying "Value of type 'Error' has no member 'code'". The second func uses exactly the same line of code but no error. I tried all sorts of things like unwrapping or not with no success.

Adding an 0 for example lets the code compile, but will off course break as soon as there is an error.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: im not familiar with firebase, but are you sure the `error` where the compile error is is the same type (aka NSError) as the `error` in the 2nd function? i have a feeling firebase is returning you its own error type and not an NSError... (since the type is omitted in the blocks parameter list, i cant tell)

Comment: Firebase has indeed it's own list of error codes and I also think we are getting Firebase error types, which should all be Int's.

Could you explain to me why the error's are of a different type in both func's?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you're asking what is the difference between these two lines of code (which you describe as *"exactly the same"*:

```
if let errorCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!.code)  {
if let errorCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error.code) {
```

When printed together the difference becomes obvious.  In the first line `error!` means that error must never be nil at that point.  Therefore you get a runtime error if it is.  In the second line `error` can be nil and, if it is, then the let statement will fall through to the `else` or next following statement as applicable.

As a general rule, avoid using ! to force non-nil values in your code unless you're 101% certain it will always be the case.

Comment: Thank you, for your remark. One question though, as the code checks that error isn't nil in the line above, I figured it could safely be unwrapped.

What I don't understand is why I get the no member notification.

Comment: Probably because that first line contradicts itself.  You are checking for a possible nil value in something that cannot be nil.  error!.code can never return a nil value so checking for nil makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so changing error!.code to error!._code solved my issue. Thank you guys for responding and trying to figure this out, much appreciated.